# Xpath expression is not working in chrome console

Tags: xml, xpath

[image]

have I did something wrong? my xpath expression is not valid..

Comment: Post actual code, not screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you have this

```
$x("//div[@class='darkrow1'])")
```

What you want is this

```
$x("//div[@class='darkrow1']")
```

Notice the former has an extra (and unmatched) closing parenthesis, ie `)`

You have made this same typo in all of your queries.